# VB.NET Reload public variable as new control

Tags: vb.net, controls, dispose, public

My question is how do you programmatically reload a public variable as new control after disposing it?

Basically I have a public control in my module like:

```
Public ComboBox_Subgroup As New ComboBox
```

And after disposing it, I need to bring it back again as a public combobox. The disposing is done like

```
    Sub Dispose_Controls(ByVal sender As Object)

        sender.Controls.Clear()

        For Each control In sender.Controls
            control.Dispose()
        Next
    End Sub
```

Basically I have some code that programmatically creates this control, but I can only run it once because of disposing. So, again, how do you `Redim` or something a new public control?

Comment: What the `Dispose_Controls()` does is completely wrong, top to bottom -- To create and assign a new Control to the Field, just `New` another -- Set `Option Strict` to `ON`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ``option strict`` has nothing to do with this... ``Dispose_Controls()`` disposes all the controls as I must clear memory and refresh the form

Comment: That's not what that code does. At all. Standard debugging steps would show why. But, think what happens there: first you clear a collection of Controls (not a collection of `Object`), then you try to iterate that collection, with a `For Each` loop. If the collection was not empty, you would dispose of half of the Controls it contained (debugging still would help). Here, all Controls are still well alive. You disposed of nothing -- Setting `Option Strict` to `ON` is a first step in the right direction, it's related to with everything

Comment: No other dispose methods did not actually clear any memory

Comment: Change `Sub Dispose_Controls(ByVal sender As Control)`, don't clear the `Controls` collection, make a backward `For` loop to dispose of the child Controls. Or a forward loop and dispose at `0` -- BTW, `Controls.Clear()` removes the Controls from the collection ONLY, it doesn't dispose of anything. All those Controls are still *alive*

Comment: But is there a way to do ``Dim Combobox_control as new combobox`` in sub on runtime but that ``Combobox_control `` to be publicly accessible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252106/discussion-between-eduards-and-jimi).

Comment: You don't `Dim` a Field that has already been defined as `Public` (which is also wrong). You just assign the instance of a `New` Control, then add it back to the `Controls` collection of its former Parent

Comment: "Basically I have some code that programmatically creates this control, but I can only run it once because of disposing." Show us that code please.